# Install webstorm but no jdk found on ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: java, ubuntu, webstorm

I am trying to install webstorm, but when I try to run the *.sh file it gives me error of not having java environment available.

So I tried to look into the [official documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/system-requirements-and-installation.html)

But the steps to install the jdk didn't worked. I tried to locate java folder, but couldn't locate this directory /usr/bin/java

Please guide me how I can install webstorm now?

Answer (score 1):

Java generally installs in  `/usr/lib/jvm/java-[major version]-openjdk-[arch]`. Install a package such as `openjdk-7-jdk` and check in that location.

If you already have java installed, running `which java` will tell you the path of the java executable.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

I haven't tried with java-8. Then:

```
sudo update-alternatives --java
```

And set auto-mode or java-7 (You might try with java-8)

Answer (score 0):

First check the about java version

> java -version

if its not returning you need to check your installed jdk

go to

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm
```

if you are finding something which start with `java_XXXX`

it means this is the only your jdk, and you can set JAVA_HOME as well path till bin folder by using export

Comment: on running java -version I see The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>

Comment: it means JAVA is not installed in your server. For the same you first have to install it.Use sudo apt-get install <selected package> and install it first, but make sure you can have sudo password

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, during installation of `eclipse` (`openjdk-7-jdk` was required). I used

```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install ...
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should just install a JRE (to allow Java execution programs) and not a JDK (to *develop* Java programs).

No need a JDK to allow Webstorm to lauch.

On ubuntu : `apt-get install default-jre`

Have a nice day :)

David